# Burst/flooded api request from iOS client

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I have an app which makes 100-200 api calls per day, and we have over 5000 daily active users. Out of these, 1, or 2 devices seem to be in a situation where they send 10,000 requests within 30-50 seconds. Of course the server can identify these situation and throttle them, but I am trying to wrap my head around how this can happen. This has happened only in two devices thus far, but I am unable to understand why/how this can happen..

We have confirmed that these are from actual clients, and not from malicious hacker. And no, there are no for-loops in the logic, it a user opens up a profile on the app, that will cause an api call. In this exact case, it's 10000 profile api requests.

Any iOS engineers have had this problem before?  I am using the AFNetworkingLibrary and the calls are as simple as below...

```
 AFHTTPRequestOperation *requestOperation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        [requestOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
         {
                ...
         } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             ...
                       }];

        [requestOperation start];
```

**Two part question:**

1. What is the reason for this bursty requests? Any issues with such a popular library?
2. How can I detect this problem on the client - any background modes or iOS behavior to be aware of?

Comment: The request is not that important. The important thing is: **where** are you doing your request? AFNetworking is fine and works OK, so I assume the method that calls makes the request is being messaged multiple times.

Comment: 'where' am i doing the request. I think you want the exact place in app where that call is made - there is nothing to worry about that one. The call is made only once when a profile needs to be seen. As mentioned out of around 20,000 users who have used our app, this has happened only 2 times. But there has to be a reason behind this.

Comment: Yes, but **where**? I mean: in `viewDidLoad`? `viewDidLayoutSubviews`? `viewWillAppear:`? Almost every method of that kind gets called more than once in a view controller lifecycle, with -probably- the sole exception of `viewDidLoad`...

Comment: Dude. Ok. It's called in viewDidLoad.  I am past these trivial reasons, I think the real answer is something different.

Comment: You might not have any for loops, but do you have any timers that trigger this request? You said this has only happened on 2 Devices so far, what was different about this devices compared to the majority of your users?

Comment: @AlejandroIván is right - it probably comes down to a case where you are making the request and some condition forces a loop. AFNetworking is thoroughly tested and won't have issues where your trivial request is sent thousands of times. Can you detail your requests and their success/error conditions?

Comment: @CStreel Nothing is different about their devices. They have also been using the app for over 90+ days. There just seems to be one instance where this happened on each of their devices

Comment: @Legolas can you post the entire function in your question, there may very well be some underlying issue in your functions implementation